# Input and output of a c code from file in android (without root)

Tags: android, c, freopen

For **OJ** problem solving I often face importance to have my outputs as a file. But **freopen()** does not work in android. Actually, there is a way that copy the code in a root diretory using **Termux** (or like apps) and then

```
./a.out <input.txt> output.txt
```

But it is very long process. Is there any way to doing this **input/output** easily any app or method?

Comment: removed, the c++ tag, not sure, but may it also isnt really about c...

Comment: I know, but freopen() is a function of c/c++. That's why I added c & c++ tag @tobi303

Comment: There is no such thing like C/C++. These are 2 different languages. Please only use the tags for the language you are using.

Comment: imho C++ got the worst name ever. Maybe ++C would have been better to make it more obvious that `C != ++C` ;) (btw `c & c++` as well as `c/c++` is undefinded both in c and c++ afaik)

Comment: I thought all the codes in c runs successfully in c++ @gerhardh

Comment: No, that's simply not true.